# Best version for Dell Mini 1210

Tags: dell, dell-mini-10

I went from Ubuntu version 8 something to 13.04 and the system is slow to the point of unuseable.  Is there something I can do with 13.04 to make it work or should I install an earlier version?  If so what version?
Thank you, Hap

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my eee-pc which is specced somewhat below the mini 1210. I reverted to 12.04 which is an LTS (supported until 2017!), and doesn't require graphics acceleraction. 12.04 is not exactly snappy either on such an old machine, but I find it very acceptable.